# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on a struct assignment -- no idea why this happens

Tags: iphone, opencv, exc-bad-access

My program crashes on the line

```
params.hessianThreshold = threshold;

CvSURFParams cvSURFParams(double threshold, int extended)
{
    CvSURFParams params;
    params.hessianThreshold = threshold;
    params.extended = extended;
    params.upright = 0;
    params.nOctaves = 4;
    params.nOctaveLayers = 2;
    return params;
}
```

I have no idea why it would crash on a static assignment ... any ideas?

Comment: If I am not wrong, in Objective-C, every thing is a reference. So, you should **new** the `params` and use it. Just to test, check whether `params` is **null** or not.

Comment: Does the calling function try to store the result in a invalid pointer? If so, this could be caused by compiler optimization, since the return is performed by passing the address of the destination and writing to it.

Comment: Do you have `double hessianThreshold;` in the `struct` declaration?

Comment: Please show declaration of CvSURFParams

Answer (score 0):

If that code is in the header, it should be `static inline CvSURFParams cvSURFParams(double threshold, int extended)` (Add a `static inline` to it). If it's not in the header, put it in the header.